# Why can I make an edit that is visible immediately but approving someone else's edit requires other people to approve it?

Tags: discussion, edits, questions, suggested-edits

I was about to make an edit to a page, noticed it had a pending edit that did the same thing and approved it.   However, for it to be visible, it requires another approval.

What is the logic behind the difference in requirements for different ways for me to change the content of a question?

Also, after I approve an edit, I don't seem to be able to edit the question directly any longer -- at least not until after the edit is approved.

Comment: not a very satisfying answer over there...

Comment: It's much easier to approve an edit (just hit a button), and you get badges if you do it enough times. That gives an incentive to "robo-review". But if you edit it yourself then it takes some effort, and if you have sufficient rep then you can be trusted to make edits without review.

Comment: That's unfortunate if decisions impacting the ability to make questions better are determined by fear of people misbehaving for badges.  If that's really the problem, maybe fix the badges?  Or maybe adding the ability to approve other people's edits immediately at a higher reputation?

Comment: It's not like the post can't be edited, it just takes a little longer for the edit to be approved.

Comment: @Null if anyone else sees it to approve it.  There's certainly a timeliness factor involved in helping a question get more attention by properly formatting it or whatever.

Comment: The edit review queue is extremely short.  If you participate more in the community in question your reputation with that community will increase which means you will be trusted to instantly approve your proposed edits.  If you want to approve other people's edits by yourself become a moderator.

Comment: @Ramhound participate more in the community changes things how?  I can already make my own edits -- that was the entire point of the question, right?

Comment: Robo-reviewers are more of a problem than the occasional post that has a delayed edit due to a suggested edit that takes a long time in review.

Comment: What is being done about robo-reviewers?